# longLongvalue from Objective C in Java?

Tags: java, android, objective-c

How to convert this Objective C code in Java ?

```
NSMutableString * thisPart = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
UInt64 intVal = (UInt64)[thisPart longLongValue];
if (!intVal) { isBad = YES; break; }
```

I've been searching over the internet but didn't find any useful information over the internet.

If I had :

```
UInt32 _tmpPacket_packetId;
_tmpPacket_packetId = (UInt32)intVal;  // UInt64 intVal = (UInt64)[thisPart longLongValue];
```

Can I do this :

```
BigInteger tmpPacket_packetId = intVal;
```

Actually the right question is : Is it right to do that to get the same thing as done in Objective C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you don't care about the NSMutableString bit which would probably similar to the StringBuilder/StringBuffer classes. A UInt64 would appear to be a 64bit unsigned int? Then you could use the String constructor provided by [BigInteger(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29)

```
StringBuilder thisPart = new StringBuilder("12345678901234567890");
try {
    BigInteger intVal = new BigInteger(thisPart.toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Bad value");
    isBad = true;
    break; // or return or what have you
}
```

Comment: Actually it's kinda work.But now I have an error doing this :  *** thisPart=tmp.substring(lastLoc, needsSize); ** where *** String tmp=incomingData.toString(); //(incomingData is byte[]). *** and it's saying to convert thisPart to String.

Comment: Then don't use StringBuilder, just use String. I was going by the fact that you were using an NSMutableString in Objective-c.

Comment: And last question if I had this : *** _tmpPacket_packetId = (UInt32)intVal; *** where *** UInt32 _tmpPacket_packetId *** Can I do this : BigInteger tmpPacket_packetId = intVal; //not really sure if it will be right as in Objective C...

Comment: Could you add that part to your question, I'm finding it difficult to read in the comments.

Comment: Actually as I made a research about Java primitive data types I saw that byte = 8bit, short  = 16bit, int = 32bit and long= 64bit. Can I use them instead of UInt64,Uint32,Uint8 in Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "1234567890";
long l = Long.parseLong(str);
```

You'll need error handling around the parse call.

Comment: It's giving me this error :  Cannot invoke longValue() on the primitive type long.

Comment: You don't need the `longValue()`, it will be auto-unboxed (at least in Java > 5, or so). Edit: Actually as Bombastic found, `parseLong` returns a primitive `long`, but if it had returned `Long`, this comment would apply.

Comment: I'm was assuming the UInt64 is an unsigned long, so you'll have issues with overflow. But if it's not, then this works.

Comment: @Rulmeq Only if the number is actually used in calculations. If it's just stored and later e.g sent over a network, you can store unsigned numbers in a signed long just fine. Edit: But now that I think of it, that seems an unlikely use case when parsing from a string.

Comment: Early morning brainfart, I edited to remove the unnecessary `longValue`.