# Objective-C and Java Primitive Data Types

Tags: java, objective-c, primitive-types

I need to convert a piece of code from Objective-C to Java, but I have a problem understanding the Primitive Types in Objective-C. So I had their data types in my Objective-C code :

`UInt64, Uint32, UInt8` ,

which are unsigned integers (as I understand from internet). So my question is, can I use Java primitive types like `byte` (8bit) -  instead of `UInt8`, `int` (32bit) - instead of `UInt32`, and `long` (64bit) - instead of `UInt64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't a straight translation and without knowing more about your program, its hard to suggest what the "right" approach is.

- If your UInt8 values really range from 0-255, you may have to use Java signed `int` to be able to hold the entire range.
- If you are dealing with byte streams or memory layouts and really need to use just a single byte of memory, than you could try `byte`, but you may have to test and handle cases to handle when the high-bit is set (value > 127).  Ditto with the other unsigned types.

Ideally, if your code just kind of "defaulted" to the unsigned types, but really the signed versions would have worked fine too (i.e. the ranges of your values never equal or exceed 2^7, 2^15, or 2^31 respectively), then you may be fine with the "straight" translation to `byte`, `int`, and `long`.

Comment: Actually here is a code which I'm trying to convert to Java from Objective C,where I need to know how is it right to do it as I said :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204306/longlongvalue-from-objective-c-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those are the correctly sized data types to use in Java. Make sure you take into account that [Java does not have unsigned types](http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned.shtml) and the trick is to use the next largest size. 64 bit unsigned arithmetic requires special consideration.